# Analysis and understanding of a tkinter code fragment

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, tkinter, super

I'm Brian!
I have some experience with Python 2, 3 and tkinter. However, I could never fully understand the way this common tkinter piece of code used by the majority of python programmers which use the tkinter module:

To ensure I have appropiate responses from people, this question is about the following themes: **Classes, Inheritance, super() built in function**, and **"master" parenting in tkinter**. *They are already included in the tags section.*

---

### The Code

I know it's boring, but in order to reply the question I need to give you a clear concept of what I am looking for, implying that this question is about code understanding/reasoning.

We start with this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.lbl = Label(master,text="This is a label sample.")
        self.lbl.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
program = App(root)
program.mainloop()
```

And our objective is to understand what's the importance/role in overriding the parent's class **init**() method with the indicated "master", if all of our internal widgets will won't exactly have the parent's class class as their master, instead the tkinter Tk() object. (You will understand better the proposal with the analysis).

### Analysis

The code starts with the statement `import tkinter as tk`. Then we can use the `tk` namespace as a reference to the `tkinter` module.

[IMAGE001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vbqF.png)

The next line declares a new class called "App", which becomes child of and inherits the "tk.Frame" methods.

[IMAGE002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBREW.png)

Taking as a reference the code (for easier understanding):

```
root = tk.Tk()
program = App(root)
```

*Now we can refer to the parameters with an actual valid name*

`tk.Tk()` gets passed as a parameter on **App()'s** `__init__()` method: 
*So we add it in the graphic.*

[IMAGE003](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV78b.png)

As the `App()` instance gets created, `self` references to the instance `program`, and `master` references `root` which is `tk.Tk()`.

The next line is `super().__init__(master)` which overrides `tk.Frame` `__init__()` method, inserting the `master` parameter with App's `master` value.
Therefore we can traduce this as `tk.Frame.__init__(tk.Tk())`

[IMAGE004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL9et.png)

Then a `tk.Label()` widget gets created with `Label(master,text="This is a label sample.")`, putting App()'s master parameter as the Label()'s widget master.

[IMAGE005](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEpeJ.png)

After that, the `tk.Label()` widget gets packed (which is insignificant for the question).

### The Concept and the Question

[IMAGE005](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEpeJ.png)

**Now, according to some programmers, the** `App(tk.Frame)` **and** `super().__init__(master)` **lines are to create a Frame widget where all elements stated in** `App()` **will take place.**

But the matter is that...

**Why do we have to setup that environment, if as you see in the following graphic, the** `tk.Label()`**'s master is** `tk.Tk()` **NOT** `tk.Frame`**?**
**Is there some concept misunderstanding by me and those two statements have an actual importance in the code?**

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: The point in super is so you do not have to pass anything. `super().__init__()` will work just fine. Also the code you provided does not make much sense as you are inheriting form the `Frame` class but you still apply the label to the root `Tk()` window. That defeats the purpose of having a frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And our objective is to understand what's the importance/role in overriding the parent's class init() method with the indicated "master", if all of our internal widgets will won't exactly have the parent's class class as their master, instead the tkinter Tk() object.

If the internal widgets do *not* have `self` or one of its descendants as its master, you should not be inheriting from `tk.Frame`. There is simply no reason to inherit from any of the tk classes if all of the objects in that class are placed in the root window.

In other words, you should *either*

- inherit from `tk.Frame` and make all widgets created in `__init__` be a child of `self` or one of it's descendants, *or*
- do *not* inherit from tk.Frame, and place all of the widgets wherever you want.

Mixing those two techniques together makes no sense, and shouldn't be done.